# "Disk volume is write-protected" error when formatting

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, raid, fibre-channel, diskmanagement, formatting

I have an Infortrend EonStor A16F-G2430 RAID-6 connected to Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 machine via Fiber Channel QLogic 2Gb PCI-X adapter.  I am able to initialize the 8.5TB storage as GPT, and able to create a simple partition spanning the entire disk.  Assigned letter X: to the partition.

When I try to format from Explorer, command line, or disk manager, i always get "Disk volume is write-protected" error.

Please assist with formatting.

Edit:  I already saw http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971436 -- It does not apply.

Comment: This appears to be caused by fault hardware.